# Compound Index Order MySQL query

Tags: mysql, indexing, subquery, query-optimization

I'm trying optimize the following mysql query. It runs in about 2.5 seconds. I've done reading on compound indexes but I'm hoping someone can help me understand how you ORDER compound indexes with queries like these that contain multiple joins, many where conditions (including date ranges), a group by, and a order by on a calculated value. Am I missing a useful compound index? Is there a more efficient way I should be pulling data from these tables? Any help is very appreciated!

```
SELECT 
branch.name AS branch,
SUM(appointment.status =  'completed') AS `Completed`, 
SUM(appointment.status =  'cancelled') AS `Cancelled`, 
SUM(appointment.status =  'not completed') AS `Not Completed`, 
SUM(appointment.status != 'rescheduled') AS `Total`
FROM rep
JOIN customer ON rep.id = customer.rep_id
JOIN office ON rep.office_id = office.id
JOIN appointment ON customer.id = appointment.customer_id
JOIN branch ON office.branch_id = branch.id
WHERE rep.active= 1 
AND rep.group IN (1,2,3) 
AND rep.deleted = 0 
AND customer.saved = 0 
AND (customer.rep_id != appointment.closed_by OR appointment.closed_by IS NULL)
AND customer.rep_id != 0 
AND customer.deleted = 0
AND office.visible = 1 
AND office.deleted = 0 
AND appointment.date >= '2016-12-01'
AND appointment.date < '2017-11-30' 
AND appointment.current = 1 
GROUP BY branch.id
ORDER BY Completed
```

Here is the EXPLAIN output:

```
id: 1
select_type: simple
table: office
type: ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY, deleted_branchID_name, deleted_visible 
key: deleted_visible
key_len: 5
ref: const,const
rows:  73
Extra: Using index condition; Using temporary; Using filesort

id: 1
select_type: simple
table: branch
type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY
key: PRIMARY
key_len: 4
ref: office.branch_id
rows: 1
Extra: NULL

id: 1
select_type:  simple
table: rep
type: ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY, group_id, office_id, active_deleted
key: office_id
key_len: 5
ref: office.id
rows:  57 
Extra: Using index condition; Using where

id:  1
select_type:  simple
table:  customer
type: ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY, rep_id
key: rep_id
key_len: 4
ref: rep.id
rows:  61 
Extra: Using where

id: 1
select_type: simple
table: appointment
type: ref
possible_keys: date, customer_id, closedByID_date, isCurrent_date
key: customer_id
key_len: 4
ref: customer.id
rows: 1
Extra: Using where
```

Comment: Without knowing anything about your data, your query suggests the index `office(deleted, visible, branch_id)`. However, this table seems to contain only a handful of rows and thus this index will probably not help much; to choose a better strategy, you can try to identify strong filters. If e.g. 99% of your data will have `customer.saved = 1` or `appointment.current != 1`, you can try to use this to optimize your query - but it will depend on your data. Also, fro clarity, you should replace all but your last `left join` by a `join` (and the last one too if `office.branch_id` is `not null`)

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion

Remove unuseful () around on condition

```
  LEFT JOIN customer ON rep.id = customer.rep_id
  LEFT JOIN office ON rep.office_id = office.id
  LEFT JOIN appointment ON customer.id = appointment.customer_id
  LEFT JOIN branch ON office.branch_id = branch.id
```